# Regex for numerical range, show 1 and 01, but reject 0 and 00

Tags: regex

I've puzzled a lot, but can't figure out why my regex doesn't work.
It's for an input which should accept a numerical range between 0 and 40. It should reject 0 and 00, but accept 1 or 01 and further...

Where am I wrong?

`\b([1-3]?\d{1}|40)\b`

Comment: Is it for JavaScript?

Comment: It's for a Polymer <paper-input> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[1-3]?\d{1}
```

matches `0` because `[1-3]` is optional and `\d` of course includes `0`. Also, the `{1}` is a no-op - every token is matched once by definition.

You need something like this:

```
\b(0?[1-9]|[1-3]\d|40)\b
```

Comment: @Thomas: No it does not have to be.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, this was the one I'm searching for.